# angular ui-grid export csv wrong data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using the following config:
AngularJS v1.4.3,
ui-grid - v3.0.7

I have a ui-grid like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIqO5.png)

For each cell I have used a cellFilter such as:
cellFilter: 'number:2',

When I click on "Export all data as csv", the result is as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVHRo.png)

In some (random) cells appear a strange "slash" character.
Does anybody have an idea what may be happening or if this is a possible bug?